# Synchronous for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/manufacturers', 
  function(err, db) {
    db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
      for (var key in collections) { // iterate over all collections
        var manufacturer = collections[key]['name'];
        var query = {}; // and get all documents
        findDocuments(db, manufacturer, query, processData);
      }
    });
  });

var findDocuments = function(db, collection, queryObj, callback) {
  var cursor = db.collection(collection).find(queryObj);
  cursor.each(function(err, docs) {
    if (docs != null) { console.log(docs); }
  });
}
```

.. it works but only gets data from one of the collections, not all.

It appears that `for` loop ends right away, how do I make it wait until the intermediate functions are returned?

Comment: `findDocuments` is always setting `collection` to `supplier`, maybe a typo of `manufacturer`?

Comment: @chernando Sorry, typo. It works for sure, just that loop doesn't wait for the `findDocuments` to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loops run synchronously, what you need is a function.
I created a sample database with the following structure,

```
manufacturers (db)
  man1 (collection 1)
   man1doc1
   man1doc2
  man2 (collection 2)
   man2doc1
```

And ran the following code to print all documents in all collections sequentially, one collection at a time.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/manufacturers', 
function(err, db) {
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {

  if(!collections.length){
    console.log('No collections found');
    return;
  }

  function sequentialIterate(key){
    if(key === collections.length){
      console.log('All documents in all collections printed');
      return;
    }
    var manufacturer = collections[key]['name'];
    var query = {};

    db.collection(manufacturer).find(query, function(err, cursor){
       cursor.each(function(err, doc){
        if(doc){
          console.log(doc);
        }
        else{
          console.log('All documents in collection ' + manufacturer + ' printed');
          sequentialIterate(key + 1);
        }
      });
    });       
  };

  sequentialIterate(0); // kick things off

 });
});
```

Prints out the following :

```
{ _id: 57cc44fc03b65f4084865057, name: 'man2doc1' }
All documents in collection man2 printed
{ _id: 57cc44f003b65f4084865055, name: 'man1doc1' }
{ _id: 57cc44f303b65f4084865056, name: 'man1doc2' }
All documents in collection man1 printed
All documents in all collections printed
```

You can replace the console.log() with callbacks if you want.